# Modelo Dinámico

Tags: c#

Bom dia!

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu preciso de criar um modelo com campos cujos valores e tipos são definidos no resultado de utilização de outro modelo. Gostaria de saber se é possivel isto, basicamente eu faço uso de um modelo e queria utilizar os resultados dos campos para criar um novo modelo.

```
        "field_name": "project_name",
        "field_type": "varchar2",

        Objectivo ir ao fild_type e atribuir um novo elemento de um Model com o tipo que la estiver declarado e dar lhe o nome do project name

            public field_type.value field_name.value { get; set; }
```

algo deste genero...
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Um modelo herdará de outro modelo?!?

Comment: Você pode utilizar `Reflection` para criar e utilizar variáveis dinamicamente. É isso que você precisa?

Comment: Você quer declarar um método com um nome dinâmico ou acessar um? Se quiser acessar, você poderá usar Reflexão para isso, se quiser declarar, terá um pouco mais de trabalho, necessitando do Codedom para compilar um código e vincular na sessão do assembly atual.

Comment: Então, eu neste momento tenho um JSON na BD que tem uma estrutura e tenho outro que é um JSON exemplo, o suposto é criar algo que faça a validação do JSON exemplo para isso, estava a pensar criar um modelo e se o JSON obdecer aquele modelo perfeito, modelo este que seria criado dinamicamente com os valores obtido em determinados campos do outro Json Estrtutura

Comment: se é um json acho que está mais fácil colocar num dicionário que dá pra pegar a chave e o valor, se for na idéia de criar um modelo mesmo acho que você pode começar olhando por expandoobjects